# ReactJs: How to open a child component embeded with Iframe on link click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I want to open a child component which has "Iframe" . How can I embed that component when I click the link in my home page.

Any suggestion ?

//homepage.js

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="section">
          <Link role="button" onClick={onTestStart} >
            click here to open Test
          </Link>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

//Child Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Iframe from '@trendmicro/react-iframe';
class TestDialog extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const testUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL+"/testDevice/index.html";
    return (
      <Iframe src={testUrl} width="100%" height={240} />
    );
  }
}

export default TestDialog;
```

Comment: The fact that the child contains an iframe doesn't seem relevant here; you need to use two basic React mechanisms to do this: 1) a boolean state variable that turns to `true` when the user clicks your link 2) conditional rendering that renders the child as part of your parent *if* the state var is true.

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for your time. Do you mind to provide a answer or example.

Comment: Sorry, but both these are covered in the basic tutorial: https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html (points 5 & 7) - If you get stuck implementing this, feel free to update your question accordingly (but please also search SO first for existing answers, or the question will get flagged as duplicate very quickly)

Comment: Thank you . I really appreciate your time .